# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined using PostgreSQL database and django

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, postgresql, google-maps

When I click on a marker deployed from my PostgreSQL database onto a Google map it's showing the following error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

I am expecting to do a info modal to pop-up and show some information. The information that should show up is being posted to the database from a form on my website via an `AJAX` call. The marker shows up in the correct position but I get the *Uncaught TypeError* when I click it

Here is my **AJAX call**:

```
const commitNewCafe = function () {
  let name = document.getElementById("venueName").value;
  let type = document.getElementById("venueType").value;
  let address = document.getElementById("venueAddress").value;
  let latitude = parseFloat(document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML);
  let longitude = parseFloat(document.getElementById("longitude").innerHTML);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/add_cafe/',
    data: {
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: document.querySelector('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').value,
      'venuename': name,
      'venuetype': type,
      'venueaddress': address,
      'latitude': latitude,
      'longitude': longitude
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log("Data sent");
    }
  });
}
```

**views.py** function that processes it for the database:

```
def add_cafe(request):
    if request.method == "POST":        
        new_obj = mapCafes()
        new_obj.cafe_name = request.POST.get('venuename')
        new_obj.cafe_address = request.POST.get('venueaddress')
        new_obj.venue_type = request.POST.get('venuetype')
        new_obj.cafe_long = float(request.POST.get('longitude'))
        new_obj.cafe_lat = float(request.POST.get('latitude'))

        new_obj.save()

    return render(request, 'testingland/addcafe.html')
```

This is the **AJAX** call that retrieves the data for the marker modal box:

```
$.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              url: '/electra/info_box/',
              data: {
                'venuename': ajaxData[i][0]
              },
              success: function(data) {
                var results = JSON.stringify(data).split(',');
                var cafeName = results[0].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9é ]/g, "");
                var cafeAddress = results[1].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9é ]/g, "") + "," + results[2].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9é ]/g, "");
                var cafeDescription = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet."
              
                $("#venue-modal").modal('show');
                $("#venue-name").html(cafeName);
                $("#venue-address").html(cafeAddress);
                $("#venue-description").html(cafeDescription);

                console.log(results);
              }
            });
```

Here is the info_box endpoint:

```
def info_box(request):
    template_name = 'testingland/index2.html'
    name = request.GET.get('venuename', None)
    qs = mapCafes.objects.filter(cafe_name = name) 
    return JsonResponse([
            [cafe.cafe_name, cafe.cafe_address]
            for cafe in qs
    ], safe=False)
```

And the console.log on success:

```
(3) ["[["New Cafe"", ""3 Sylvester Grove", " Preston"]]"]
0: "[["New Cafe""
1: ""3 Sylvester Grove"
2: " Preston"]]"
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: try to console.log(result) to check what you are getting

Comment: So it looks like the error is thrown when it encounters this:
```
var results = JSON.stringify(data).split(',');
```
It expects a comma for splitting the address but if none is provided then it throws the error. Is there a way to catch this?

Comment: Could you provide the code of the `/electra/info_box/ endpoint`, and like @DominikMatis requested - the printout of the `data` argument that the ajax function receives in success.

Comment: Added to OP hope that helps

Comment: Also add the raw data you getting from server